# Commutativity in Matrix operations for convolution in CV

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's say I have 2 $n$ by $n$ matrices called $A$ and $B$. If I flip $A$ left to right, then up and down, and do element-wise multiplication with matrix $B$ and sum up the elements of this new matrix, is that the same as flipping $B$ left to right, up and down, and then doing element-wise multiplication with matrix $A$ and then computing the sum? How can I prove this? Examples show it's true, but looking for a proof.

link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)

Comment: What would CV be???

Comment: @copper.hat computer vision

Comment: You need to grind through the formula. Start by flipping $A$ left to right, then the $i,j$ entry is $A(i,n-j+1)$, flipping top to bottom gives an $i,j$ entry of $A(n-i+1,n-j+1)$, compute the required sum. Repeat for $B$ and show the results are equal.

Comment: is not your operation of double flipping just the anti diagonal  transposition? The answer is a simple symmetric variable change in your sum